# Is this equivalent to Task.Run?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, task

I'm writing an F# application and I want to get rid of explicit references to task as much as possible.  Is the following equivalent to `Task.Run` or am I missing something?

```fs
[<AutoOpen>]
module Async =        
    let inline runInThreadPool backgroundTask = async {
          let originalContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current
          do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()
          let! result = backgroundTask()
          do! Async.SwitchToContext originalContext 
          return result}
```

Example usage (untested):

```fs
async { // starts on the UI thread
    let! result = Async.runInThreadPool(fun _ -> async {
        let mutable sum= 0
        for i in 1..10000 do
            sum <- sum + 1
        return sum })
    //do something with the result in the UI
} |> Async.StartImmediate
```

Comment: I don't get what this is supposed to achieve. What does it have to do with `Task`? `Task.Run` is equivalent to `Async.Start`.

Comment: Are you using APIs that deal with tasks? If so, you can easily convert those to `Async`s using `Async.AwaitTask`. In any case, I don't see the value in writing a replacement for `Async.Start`.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  I want to background some processing, and am currently using `Task.Run` with `Async.AwaitTask`.  I'm wanting to replace the `Task.Run`s with `Async`, so I want to know if the posted code is equivalent (i.e. runs on a background thread, but runs the continuation on the original thread).

Comment: I'm not sure about the threading behavior, but just comparing the docs for `Task.Run` and `Async.Start`, it seems they're the same.

Comment: The problem there is that it returns `unit` so there isn't any way to unwrap it using `let!`.

Comment: Can you show a code sample?

Comment: @Daniel Obviously contrived, but I think it illustrates what I'm looking for.

Comment: The `async { }` block already runs in the thread pool. You can just change `let! result = Async.runInThreadPool(fun _ -> async {` to `let! result = async {`.

Comment: @Daniel I checked the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` and that isn't the case.  A simple `Async` bind does not run on a new thread, while the code I gave does.

Comment: Right. It may not, or it may. Do you really care?

Comment: That makes a pretty big difference with respect to UI responsiveness.  I want to guarantee it doesn't lock up the UI.

Comment: You are apparently already in an `async { }` block when you first check the thread Id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55729/discussion-between-mydogisbox-and-daniel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Daniel pointed out, this is better achieved using `Async.StartChild` like this:

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module Async =        
    let inline runInThreadPool backgroundTask = async {
          let! result = backgroundTask() |> Async.StartChild
          return! result}
```